# Checkboxes making too many toast appear

Tags: android, if-statement, checkbox, toast

I have two checkboxes, and two EditText. OnClick of a CheckBox makes the EditText Disappear and displays the Toast `"Your Information is Saved"`. If the CheckBox is clicked again another Toast will display `"Enter Your Email Address"`. Although it's working both Toast are displaying after a single `onClick` right after each other. Any Ideas?

```
on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
      receiverEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
      "Your Information is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
      receiverEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
      "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});

on2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
      clientID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
      "Your Information is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
      clientID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
      "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `if/else` loop incorrectly. Change your `setOnClickListener's` to the following and it should work fine...

```
on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
      receiverEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Information is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      receiverEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
});

on2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
      clientID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Information is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      clientID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the curlies after the `else` statements, so the last `Toast` is always shown no matter if `CheckBox` is checked or not.

Your `else` statements should look like these:

```
else {
    receiverEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }});
}
```

and

```
else {
    clientID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "Enter Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }});
}
```

I'd always include the curly block after each if/else to avoid situations like these, when indentation would trick you into believing the second statement is part of the if/else, when it isn't.